# Snowflake error : SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on account '<Account-ID>'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a free trial account for Snowflake. I am trying to create storage integration. But after running the script I am getting below error :

SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on account ''

Even for the Account Admin role, above error is coming.

Answer (score 6):

There are two places to set your role in the Snowflake original web UI (not Snowsight). You need to make sure you're changing to the ACCOUNTADMIN role for the right context:

[image: Setting roles in Snowflake web UI]

If you're getting the error when running a SQL statement from the web UI, check your current role for the worksheet. You can click on the icon or role text to change it.

In this example, you can see that I've changed my role in the upper right to ACCOUNTADMIN, but that changes only my role for the button bar. I'm still using the SYSADMIN role when running SQL statements in a worksheet.

Also note that each worksheet has its own context, so changing worksheets could change your role if it's set differently on the worksheet you're opening.

Comment: I totally missed to check that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have faced this issue, but **while using Terraform** and specifying the provider configuration through environment variables. **I was missing the SNOWFLAKE_ROLE** to determine the role used while applying the Terraform configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error while running a deployment pipeline to an upper environment (code from DEV migrating to UAT).  It's one of those weird situations where the logged-in user has to be able to perform multiple SQL actions which may require multiple role membership.  In my case, I was running DDL 'Create' statements (as SYSTEMADMIN) and also needed to run some SQL commands which involved interacting with Snowflake Storage Integrations (which require the active role to be ACCOUNTADMIN).

```
USE SECONDARY ROLES ALL;
```

Use Secondary Roles -
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/use-secondary-roles.html

> Note that the set of roles is reevaluated when each SQL statement executes. If additional roles are granted to the user, and that user executes a new SQL statement, the newly granted roles are active secondary roles for the new SQL statement.

Including this at the top of each deployment script file removed the  'Insufficient Privileges' error and allowed successful execution of SQL scripts in my deployment pipeline.