# Ownership Priviledge on a Schema Empty in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, privileges

I've got Accountadmin role on this Snowflake account. I ran `show grants on schema` command in snowflake and get these privileges as on the screenshot.

[image]

Ownership privilege is empty and so it doesn't let me run `grant ownership on schema "DATABASE_NAME"."SCHEMA_NAME" to accountadmin` for the above schema to assign myself the ownership privilege.

I need to have ownership privilege to remove some tables from this schema.

Could someone suggest how to assign **ownership privilege** to **accountadmin** role for this schema?

Comment: If you're using the classic UI, make sure you are using the ACCOUNTADMIN role for the worksheet you're using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69481371/snowflake-error-sql-access-control-error-insufficient-privileges-to-operate-o/69481677#69481677

Answer (score 1):

This situation can be caused by user-initiated actions, if a grant is involving system owned entities (such as default) roles, and via using MANAGE GRANTS on ACCOUNT privilege to custom roles.

I would suggest opening a Support Case as we'd need to review all the grant changes that occurred on that schema to understand what caused the situation in the first place, and then revert it.

That said, you should still be able to execute this statement with either ACCOUNTADMIN or SECURITYADMIN:

```
use role accountadmin;    
grant ownership on schema "DATABASE_NAME"."SCHEMA_NAME" to role accountadmin;
```